Turtlebot4: OAK-D camera stops publishing messages after few seconds on bootup
I am facing a small issue in getting the topics from the camera on turtlebot-4.
Issue: When the robot boots up and I send the command "ros2 topic list", I see the camera topics - "/turtle/oakd/rgb/preview/image_raw" and I can access the camera using "rqt_image_view" but within 5 seconds the robot stops publishing the camera topics. That is, when I read the ros2 topic list, I do not see "/turtle/oakd/rgb/preview/image_raw" being published and I cannot access the camera.
I using Ubuntu 22.04 with ros2 humble.
Has anyone faced or heard this issue? Your help would be appreciated! Thank You!

By default the oakd nodes will shut down while the robot is docked. This is to save energy and speed up charging. The topics should return when you undock your robot. This behaviour can be changed here: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot4_robot/blob/3d92a3f2b7ea889e198352322e231a7fab540dcf/turtlebot4_bringup/config/turtlebot4.yaml#L8

Thank you, this helped! I could read camera messages when I undocked the robot.
